# How can I use aliases defined in bash profile in a backtick operation with ruby?

Tags: ruby, bash

After a long time googling and SOing…

I've got some aliases defined in my `.bash_profile` file. For instance:

```
alias say_hello="echo 'Hello!'"
```

I want to use them in a backtick operation in ruby, sourcing my bash profile. But I fail.

I tried:

```
# (ruby code)
res = `. /Users/thatsme/.bash_profile;say_hello`
# => sh: say_hello: command not found
```

Or even:

```
res = `. /Users/thatsme/.bash_profile;shopt -s expand_aliases;say_hello`
# => sh: say_hello: command not found
```

(note: I don't want to hard-code the alias in the backtick operation).

### Note

The bash profile is well sourced. If I put `echo "I'm sourced"` in it, my backtick operation echoes the text.

```
res = `. /Users/thatsme/.bash_profile;say_hello`
# => 
    sh: say_hello: command not found
    I'm sourced
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: The problem is that aliases are expanded at parse time, which means `say_hello` would need to be defined before your shell even executes either the source command *or* the `shopt` command. This is another instance where aliases just aren't suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
res = `bash -c "source /Users/thatsme/.bash_profile; shopt -s expand_aliases
say_hello"`
```

- `shopt` is needed because aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive
- `<newline>` is necessary because aliases are expanded at parse time. `bash` parses the line and tries to expand aliases. Only after that are the commands executed (including `source`). Consequently, you need to put it on a new line

Comment: @PhilippePerret I haven't rejected your edit. However, literal newline should also work and makes the code much more readable. So does `source` instead of `.`.

Comment: @PhilippePerret it doesn't work for you when copy pasted exactly like this? That is hard to believe. Also, you can see who rejected your edit on your profile under actions.

Comment: Au temps pour moi, @PesaThe. I didn't know backtick works as an heredoc… But it works, sorry. Even if I think `\n` is much clearer. I'm afraid some people doesn't understand your `<new line>`. Moreover, a real return is bad looking with indentation. And as far I know, `source` is not `.`. But it works in this case, too.

Comment: @PhilippePerret The main thing is that it works for you :) I chose "real" newline and `source` because they both made the code seem much more clear to me. `source` is the equivalent of `.`, they are synonyms, at least in `bash`. I believe `.` should be used if you are concerned about compatibility though.